# При команде старт вылазило сразу две клавиатуры обычная и инлайнова, тг бот на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я занимаюсь роз робкой своего бота  по биткоин обменнику я столкнулся с проблемой клавиатуры я бы хотел  сделать что бы при команде старт вылазило сразу две клавиатуры обычная и инлайнова.

Вот пример как я хотел что бы, выглядел мой бот при команде старт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код

```
import telebot
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sti = open('gangsta.jpg', 'rb')

    #keyboard

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Меню")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Промо код")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Наши проекты")
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Помощь")
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton(" Наш чат")

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

    b1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Купить номер', callback_data='buynumber')
    b2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пополнить баланс', callback_data='balance')
    b3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Cтрана/Оператор', callback_data='country')
    b4 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мультисервис', callback_data='myltis')
    b5 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='История покупок', callback_data='history')
    b6 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='prof')
    row1 = [b1, b2]
    row2 = [b3, b4]
    row3 = [b5]
    row4 = [b6]
    buttons = [row1, row2, row3, row4]
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)


    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, sti,' Вотсап братка!\nТебя приветствует  Geng SMS!\n Приятных покупок.'.format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Вопрос ваш в чем?

Comment: Я бы хотел знать как сделать что бы при команде /start выбивало сразу две клавиатуры инлайн и обычная

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? вы смогли вывести каждую клавиатуру по отдельности? покажите

Comment: Простите но я сюда не могу написать код потому что он большой или выслать фото, можете ли вы мне помочь командой а то я уже много методов перепробывал

Comment: В том то и дело что я не понимаю где у вас сложность, вы можете сделать [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: вот я поправил посмотрите и скажите где моя ошибка

Comment: И что не так с этим кодом? что происходит? нет инлайновой клавиатуры? нет обычной? ошибка при компиляции?

Comment: Я бы хотел что бы при команде старт у меня было сразу 2 клавиатуры а сейчас когда я нажымаю команду старт появляется только инлайн клавиатура и обычной нету и я не знаю как сделать так что бы было сразу две клавиатуры при нажатии команды старт

Answer (score 0):

Просто отправь два сообщения как сделано у тебя на скрине

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sti = open('gangsta.jpg', 'rb')

    markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        "Меню", "Промо код", "Наши проекты", "Помощь", " Наш чат")

    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Купить номер', callback_data='buynumber'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пополнить баланс', callback_data='balance')).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Cтрана/Оператор', callback_data='country'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мультисервис', callback_data='myltis')).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='История покупок', callback_data='history')).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='prof'))

    bot.send_photo(
        message.chat.id,
        photo=sti,
        caption=' Вотсап братка!\nТебя приветствует Geng SMS!\n Приятных покупок.',
        reply_markup=markup_reply)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        'Выбери что тебе интересно',
        reply_markup=markup_inline)
```